# IronRouter event function

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Does iron router have an event when the Meteor app is loaded?

I would like to run a function when template 'loading' is display, and when app is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

To display a template while loading put this line in the router file.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});
```

where  `loading` is the loading template.

Alternatively:  [pcel:loading](https://atmospherejs.com/pcel/loading) package from atmospherejs.

Comment: I've already add loading on loadingTemplate, but i don't have any event when the APP is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

### Router Hooks:

You can try to use the router hooks provided by iron-router such as `waitOn`, `onBeforeAction` etc. in conjunction with your loading template.

**For example:**

If you have a route named `path` and a subscription named `foo` being accessed on that route:

```
Router.route('/path', {
  // this template will be rendered until the subscriptions are ready
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',

  waitOn: function () {
    // perform action while database subscription loads
    console.log('Fetching foo...');
    return Meteor.subscribe('foo');
  },

  onBeforeAction() {
    // perform action before route loads
    console.log('Loading...');
    this.next();
  },

  action: function () {
    // perform action when route loads
    // ...
    this.render('myTemplate');
  },

  onAfterAction() {
    // perform action after route loads
    // ...
  }
});
```

From the official guide, there are a number of options available to perform functions at router level, depending on exactly when you want the action to initiate:

> **[Available Hook Methods](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#available-hook-methods)**
>
> - **onRun:** Called when the route is first run. It is not called again if the route reruns because of a computation invalidation. This
>     makes it    a good candidate for things like analytics where you want
>     be sure the    hook only runs once. Note that this hook won't run
>     again if the route    is reloaded via hot code push. You must call
>     this.next() to continue    calling the next function.
> - **onRerun:** Called if the route reruns because its computation is    invalidated. Similarly to onBeforeAction, if you want to continue
>     calling the next function, you must call this.next().
> - **onBeforeAction:** Called before the route or "action" function is run.    These hooks behave specially. If you want to continue calling
>     the    next function you must call this.next(). If you don't,
>     downstream    onBeforeAction hooks and your action function will not
>     be called.
> - **onAfterAction:** Called after your route/action function has run or had    a chance to run. These hooks behave like normal hooks and
>     you don't    need to call this.next() to move from one to the next.
> - **onStop:** Called when the route is stopped, typically right before a    new route is run.

### Plugins:

If you want to reuse the same functionality on multiple routes, you can create [route plugins](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#plugins) like this:

```
Iron.Router.plugins.loading = function (router, options) {
  // this loading plugin just creates an onBeforeAction hook
  router.onBeforeAction('loading', options);
};
```

Take a look at the [full guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) to try more hooks and methods that may be useful to you.